How to group an array of shapes
I am making a flow chart, where I want to group the entire flow chart for the user to move it around later if he/she wants.
I made an array of rectangular shapes and arrow respectively and named them accordingly.
However, I am not able to group them all together.
There will be more such flowcharts in the same sheet. So, I don't want to use thisSheet.Shapes option.
Following is the code that I have prepared
Dim i As Integer
Dim outer_box As Shape
Dim shp(20) As Shape
Dim arw(20) As Shape
Dim shpgrp As Shape
Dim rg As Range
Dim height As Long


 
With ActiveSheet
    Set rg = .Range("B11")
End With

i = 1
height = 0
If process(i - 1) = vbNullString Then
    End
Else
    For i = 1 To 20
        If process(i - 1) = vbNullString Then 'Separate userform where process() array gets inputs
            Exit For
        Else
            Set shp(i) = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 1, 1, 1, 1) 
            With shp(i)
                .Width = 150
                .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft
                .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                .TextFrame.Characters.Text = i & ". " & process(i - 1) 'Separate userform where process() array gets inputs
                .Left = rg.Left + 5
                .Top = rg.Top + 10 + height + 20 * (i - 1)
                .Name = "shp" & i
            End With
            If Not i - 1 = 0 Then
                Set arw(i) = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 100, 100, 100, 100)
                With arw(i)
                    .Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle
                    .ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect shp(i - 1), 3
                    .ConnectorFormat.EndConnect shp(i), 1
                    .Name = "arw" & i
                End With
            End If
        End If
        height = height + shp(i).height
    Next i
    Set outer_box = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    With outer_box
        .Top = rg.Top
        .Left = rg.Left
        .Width = 160
        .height = height + 20 * (i - 1)
        .ZOrder msoSendToBack
        .Name = "outer_box"
    End With
End If

Set shpgrp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("outer_box", "shp" & (i - 1), "arw" & (i - 1))).Group
shpgrp.Select
End Sub

I am only able to group the last shapes. How do I group the array of shapes and arrows here?
Is it possible to iteratively add the shapes and arrows as into a group, when the for loop is running?
Thank you.


Collect all shapes' name and create an array with Split

Microsoft documentation:

Split function

Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim outer_box As Shape
    Dim shp(20) As Shape
    Dim arw(20) As Shape
    Dim shpgrp As Shape
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim sShpList As String
    Dim height As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rg = .Range("B11")
    End With
    i = 1
    height = 0
    If process(i - 1) = vbNullString Then
        End
    Else
        sShpList = "outer_box"
        For i = 1 To 20
            If process(i - 1) = vbNullString Then 'Separate userform where process() array gets inputs
                Exit For
            Else
                Set shp(i) = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                With shp(i)
                    .Width = 150
                    .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft
                    .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = i & ". " & process(i - 1) 'Separate userform where process() array gets inputs
                    .Left = rg.Left + 5
                    .Top = rg.Top + 10 + height + 20 * (i - 1)
                    .Name = "shp" & i
                    sShpList = sShpList & "|" & "shp" & i
                End With
                If Not i - 1 = 0 Then
                    Set arw(i) = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 100, 100, 100, 100)
                    With arw(i)
                        .Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle
                        .ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect shp(i - 1), 3
                        .ConnectorFormat.EndConnect shp(i), 1
                        .Name = "arw" & i
                        sShpList = sShpList & "|" & "arw" & i
                    End With
                End If
            End If
            height = height + shp(i).height
        Next i
        Set outer_box = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        With outer_box
            .Top = rg.Top
            .Left = rg.Left
            .Width = 160
            .height = height + 20 * (i - 1)
            .ZOrder msoSendToBack
            .Name = "outer_box"
        End With
    End If
    Set shpgrp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Split(sShpList, "|")).Group
    shpgrp.Select
End Sub

